# How to force javascript function execute synchronously/sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I am creating a utility method which helps fading the elements sequentially with jQuery. As you can see in the below code I am adding an extra class as `alreadyFadedIn` a flag. At the end of the method call `sequentiallyFadeIn(...)` I would like to perform the `cleanUp` where I want to remove the flag class which I added in the selected elements inside the `sequentiallyFadeIn(...)` method.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    function sequentialFadeIn(selectorText, speed, display, callBack) {

        display = typeof display !== 'undefined' ? display : "block";

        function helper() {
            nextElementToFadeIn = $(selectorText).not(".alreadyFadedIn").first();
            nextElementToFadeIn.fadeIn(speed, function() {
                $(this).addClass("alreadyFadedIn");
                helper();
            }).css("display", display);
        }
        helper();

        callBack(selectorText);      
    }
    sequentialFadeIn(".toBeFaddedIn", "slow", "inline-block",function cleanUp(selectorText1){
            $(selectorText1).removeClass("alreadyFadedIn");
            console.log("Clean up has been performed.");
                    console.log("Selector Text: " +selectorText1);

        } );

});

</script>

</head>
<body><style media="screen" type="text/css">
.hello {
    background-color: blue;
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: none;

}
</style>

<div class="hello toBeFaddedIn"></div>
<div class="hello toBeFaddedIn"></div>
<div class="hello toBeFaddedIn"></div>
<div class="hello toBeFaddedIn"></div>
<div class="hello toBeFaddedIn"></div>

</body></html>
```

While looking at the inspect element I notice that class `alreadyFadedIn` is not getting removed. The cause seems to me is the cleanUp method gets executed asynchronously along with main logic of the `sequentiallyFadeIn` method which is in `helper()`. You can also notice the log message "Clean up has been performed." getting printed even before the divs have completed fading in.

How can I make the `cleanUp` call getting executed after the completion of main logic in the `sequentiallyFadedIn` method? Any suggestions?

Code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/11/

Comment: Looks like you have to run the callback inside the `helper` function once `nextElementToFadeIn` does not contain any element anymore.

Comment: You need to call the `callBack` function in the completion function of `fadeIn`.

Comment: Your code executes `helper` (which removes the class `alreadyFadedIn`) immediately, and the anonymous function which adds the class `alreadyFadedIn` is executed later, when the fadeIn animation is complete. That seems wrong. But you have the ingredients there to fix the logic. You can execute code immediately or on animation end.

Comment: This looks overly complicated. Why not chain fade-in using next(), without the need for adding a class?

Comment: @FelixKling your solution worked ! : ) Here is the updated code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/14/

Comment: @Christophe I would love to see your simpler version! Can you post a solution and comment back here a demo link please?

Comment: @Atharva sure, I have added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check whether any elements remain to be faded in. If no elements remain, call the cleanup callback. Here is how I implemented it:

```
    if ($(selectorText).is(":not(.alreadyFadedIn)")) {

        //Your main logic
        nextElementToFadeIn = $(selectorText).not(".alreadyFadedIn").first();
        nextElementToFadeIn.fadeIn(speed, function() {
            $(this).addClass("alreadyFadedIn");
            helper();
        }).css("display", display);

    } else {

        //No elements remain, cleanup time
        callBack(selectorText);
    }
```

In the outer condition I check whether there is at least one element that is not faded in, otherwise I invoke the callback.

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/12/

Comment: I also came up with something similar based on @FelixKing's suggestion in the comments under the question. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/14/

Answer (score 3):

Easier, cleaner and faster if you just rewrite your code something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function sequentialFadeIn(selectorText, speed, display, callBack) {

        display = display || "block";

        var els = $(selectorText),
              i = 0;

        (function helper() {
            els.eq(i++).fadeIn(speed, helper).css("display", display);
            if (callback && i === els.length)
                callback(selectorText); // Not really needed any more
        })();
    }

    sequentialFadeIn(".toBeFaddedIn", "slow", "inline-block", function cleanUp(selectorText1){
        // not really needed any more
       //  $(selectorText1).removeClass("alreadyFadedIn");
    });
});
```

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/15/

You were doing *way* more DOM selection than needed.

Comment: Aah ! Beautiful : ) When we have the `.eq()` as looper, who needs the extra flags! Thanks for pointing out this way.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment, here is a simplified version that doesn't use an additional class:

```
function fadeThenNext(element){
    element.fadeIn("fast", function() {
        element=element.next(".toBeFaddedIn");
        if (element.length) fadeThenNext(element);
    });
}
fadeThenNext($(".toBeFaddedIn").first());
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/17/

**[Update]** A more generic version if the elements are not siblings:

```
function fadeSequence(elements){
    elements.first().fadeIn("fast", function() {
        fadeSequence(elements.slice(1));
    });
}
fadeSequence($(".toBeFaddedIn"));
```

​fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BztLx/22/

Comment: It requires the elements selected to be siblings of each other, it may not be the case sometimes. But applicable to some scenarios where this effect needs to be applied say on a list of elements.

Comment: right, for a more generic code you'll need to iterate through the selector as in @user1689607 's sample. The point is that you don't need the extra class!